# Importing mulitple HTML content into a page using a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to import HTML content, not the entire page to a new page.

The problem is I have to create document load function for each item I need to load. Is there a way to do this in a single function? Meaning different content gets imported every time I click a link? So if I want to import another DIV content, I have to create an entire duplicate.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.using-this-button').click(function() {
      $('.importHere').load('from-here.php  #just-this-part');
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting it up dynamically. I assume you will be using different links to setup differnet pieces of content.

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a.dynamic_load').click(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $($el.data('dest')).load($el.data('src'), $el.data('target'));
      });       
    });
```

HTML

```
    <a href="url.php" data-src="url-to-retrieve-data.php" data-dest=".element-to-replace" data-target="#element-to-retrieve-data-from">click here</a>
```